# Mixture of discrete and continuous distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, mixing

I have a question about how to find the pdf of a random variable $Z$ which is a sum and product of continuous AND discrete random variables.

More specifically, I know that $X$ is Bernoulli($p$) and I have an expression for the continuous pdf of $Y$, as 
\begin{align*}
f_y(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
... \qquad & \text{for } t \in [a,b] \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{align*}
How would I find the pdf of $Z=XY$ ? If anyone could help me/has a good reference for this kind of question I would really appreciate.

Thank you very much

Comment: I am really stuck on this one, would it be useful to consider the conditional probabilities ?

Comment: I believe your question is a special case of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316071/what-is-the-pdf-of-a-product-of-a-continuous-random-variable-and-a-discrete-rand