# What is the PDF of a product of a geometric random variable and an exponential random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a geometric random number, and $Y$ be an exponential random number. Then PDF of $X$ will be 
\begin{equation}
f_X(x)=p(1-p)^x
\end{equation}
 and 
\begin{equation}
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{t}\exp\left(-\frac{y}{t}\right).
\end{equation}
 Let $Z=XY$, then what is the PDF of a new random number? Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316071/what-is-the-pdf-of-a-product-of-a-continuous-random-variable-and-a-discrete-rand# possible duplication

Comment: @daveS this is definitely not a duplicate

Comment: well???????????

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this via MGF. Let $\phi$ be the MGF of $X$

$Ee^{uXY}=E[E[e^{uXY}|X]]=E[E[e^{uxY}]|_{x=X}]=E[(\frac{1/t}{1/t-u})^Y]=\phi(\log(\frac{1/t}{1/t-u}))=\frac{p/t}{p/t-u}$

that means the distribution of $XY$ is ? with parameter $p/t$

Fill in a few gaps.

Comment: I may need to read about MGF, but the answer is similar to what I expected. Thank you very much.